# modify ajax call from fiddle

Tags: xml, ajax

i got ajax call from fiddle like below. how to modify the ajax call to function on my hosting server?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
//for fiddle demo xml had to be loaded in this way
//use your own ajax call for your page
$.ajax({
    url: "/echo/xml/", //your url
    type: "POST", //may not need this-fiddle did-default is GET
    dataType: "xml", 
    data: {
        xml: "<geonames><geoname><name>London</name><geonameId>2643743</geonameId><countryCode>GB</countryCode><countryName>United Kingdom</countryName></geoname><geoname><name>London</name><geonameId>6058560</geonameId><countryCode>CA</countryCode><countryName>Canada</countryName></geoname><geoname><name>The Tower of London</name><geonameId>6286786</geonameId><countryCode>GB</countryCode><countryName>United Kingdom</countryName></geoname></geonames>"
    }, //should not need to define 'data' on your own xml call
    success: function(xmlResponse) {
        var data = $("geoname", xmlResponse).map(function() {
            return {
                value: $("name", this).text() + ", " + ($.trim($("countryName", this).text()) || "(unknown country)"),
                id: $("geonameId", this).text()
            };
        }).get();
        $("#test").autocomplete({
            source: function(req, response) {
                var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
                response($.grep(data, function(item) {
                    return matcher.test(item.value);
                }));
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("p#result").html(ui.item ? ui.item.id : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            }
        });
    }
});
});//]]>  

</script>
```

please give some modify sample on above codes

Comment: How can your code be modified without knowing your requirement, Please specify your need along with the code your tried so far

Comment: my requirement is to modify the ajax call code above to work on my hosting server. it's u did not understand what the question is..

Comment: May be you should show some respect to the fellow members ok. People here are volunteers who help people on theirs doubts , not to do modifications on some copied code.

Comment: make sure u understand what the question is before u give negatif reputation, dude. respect is only for the one who can respect other

Comment: I didn't downvote you ok, Please dont  underestimate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
//for fiddle demo xml had to be loaded in this way
//use your own ajax call for your page
$.ajax({
    url: "your.xml", //change with your xml url
    type: "POST", //may not need this-fiddle did-default is GET
    dataType: "xml", 

    success: function(xmlResponse) {
        var data = $("geoname", xmlResponse).map(function() {
            return {
                value: $("name", this).text() + ", " + ($.trim($("countryName", this).text()) || "(unknown country)"),
                id: $("geonameId", this).text()
            };
..........
```